# Visual Studio Code - empty CSS ruleset

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

Quando crio uma class no HTML e vou pro CSS e coloco ".alguma_Class{}" o arquivo css nao reconhece essa class na busca automática e so funciona se eu digitar tudo na mão e so depois disso é que começa a aparecer na busca automática e sem falar quando digito a class aparece o erro que ta no print. Não estava assim, ficou assim do nada. Alguem sabe dizer pq?

[image: Error]

[image: erro]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre no arquivo .CSS vc não conseguir auto completar uma classe que só exite no HTML isso está documentado aqui: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28442

Acredito que vc deve ter se confundido, pois como vc pode ver no `GitHub` do projeto essa *feature* ainda não foi desenvolvida...

---

Seu problema com o "`erro`" é que vc não está colocando nenhuma propriedade dentro da classe. Em suma, vc tem uma classe `.some-class { vazia }` que não tem nenhum propriedade dentro ai da o `alerta`.

Exemplo do mesmo erro no console na aba `Problems` do VS Code

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No VS Code, vc pode desabilitar esse tipo de alerta indo em `Settings` e configurando as preferencias para arquivos de CSS conforme imagem abaixo.

Entra em `Settings`, na barra de pequisa procure por "empt" localize dentro de `Extensions` o tópico `CSS` e coloca `Ignore`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Veja que apos ajustar para `Ignore` o erro não aparece mais na aba `Problems` ou no arquivo CSS**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Show de bola mano... Obg... Mas esse era metade do problema, a outra é o autocomplete... Se vc colocar uma class em qualquer elemento no html e depois for la no CSS e locar ".classquevcquer", autocomplete nao acha aquela class... mas... se vc colocar ela escrevendo todinha pelo menos uma vez, na proxima vez q vc for escrever esse class no documento CSS, ai o autocomplete já reconhece... tendeu?

Comment: Até onde eu sei esse é o comportamento normal do VS Code, não lebre de no CSS ele reconhecer uma classe que só existe no HTML e fazer o autocomplet... nunca reparei nesse comportamento no arquivo .css autocompletanto uma classe que só está no HTML...

Comment: O que eu sei é que o IntelliSense por exemplo no HTML completa as classes que já estão discritas no .CSS... Vc pode olhar aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45865053/vs-code-detect-css-classes-and-ids-from-html-and-autocomplete e ver que existe algumas extenções que pode te ajudar. Veja o Edite que fiz logo no início da minha resposta.